# Sliding Window Algorithm to detect certain numbers

Tags: matlab

I have a project to detect numbers from guitar tablature (The Coordinates Location and The numbers). Here is an example of tablature:

[image: Guitar Tablature]

First, I've done some pre-processing.

The 2nd step is segmentation. This step goals are to remove lines, get the numbers and store the coordinates of each number.

I think if I implement the Sliding Window Algorithm it'll be easy to detect them.

I've tried `blockproc` but I don't know how exactly to use it. Any other function recommendations would be appreciated.

Also some codes (it's just for display the cropped images by 100px):

```
clc;clear all;`   
image = imread('tabTes.png');
imageWidth = size(image, 2);
imageHeight = size(image, 1);
windowWidth = 100;
windowHeight = 100;
for j = 1:imageHeight - windowHeight + 1
    for i = 1:imageWidth - windowWidth + 1
        SlideWindow = image(j:j + windowHeight - 1, i:i + windowWidth - 1, :);
         figure
         imshow(SlideWindow);
     end
end
```

Comment: You already asked this today.

Comment: Sorry this question is different than before @beaker

Comment: Okay, what is your approach for detecting the numbers? All you're doing at this point is displaying different windows of the image.

Comment: Yep i know that. 

I've thought some algorithm in my mind but i can't implement in on code.


Given some image (300px) of guitar tablature. that image contains certain numbers and lines that have at least 3 px and 1 px for lines.
I think, if i make sliding window (3 by 3) i can detect those numbers.

So this my algorithm:

`if (Sliding_wind found at least 3 px) then

   there are character

   crop image

   store the coordinate

else if (Sliding_win found just 2 px) then

   there are line

else

  stop

end`

Comment: It would be really helpful if you added all of that context to the question itself as well as your desired output.

Comment: ok i'll edit it asap

Comment: I'd be really curious to find out who bothered to make images of tab text files.

Comment: It'll use for help illiterate 'cause the output from this project is MIDI format.

Comment: But those tab files were originally ASCII text files, which makes OCR unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

I hate doing this, but cant stop it.

```
im=imread(..);

% rgb to gray
im2=rgb2gray(im);

% threshold
im_bw=im2<240;

% remove some clutter
im3=imopen(im_bw,ones(2,1));
[x,y]=find(im3);
im4=bwselect(im_bw,y,x,4);
im5 = imclose(im4,strel('disk',5));
im5 = bwmorph(im5,'thicken',2);

% bounding boxes
s=regionprops(im5,'PixelIdxList','Centroid','BoundingBox');
bboxes=cat(1,s.BoundingBox);
Iocr = insertShape(im, 'Rectangle', bboxes,'Color','blue');

figure; imshow(Iocr,[]);
hold all

% use OCR
for i=1:numel(s)    
    tmp=ceil(s(i).BoundingBox);
    tmp=im_bw(tmp(2):tmp(2)+tmp(4),tmp(1):tmp(1)+tmp(3),:);
    txt=ocr(tmp,'CharacterSet','0123456789');    
    text(s(i).Centroid(1),s(i).Centroid(2),txt.Text,'Color','r')    
end
```

[image]

Comment: Note: this requires the Computer Vision toolbox, which the OP may or may not have (they must have the Image Processing toolbox for `blockproc` but still...). Other than that, solid results!

Comment: OMG @FirdausyAngga !!